# Running a MongoDB sleep() command from ReactiveMongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I'm trying to use Spring 5's ReactiveMongoTemplate to run a [sleep()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sleep/) command in MongoDB, and create a slow database call. The scriptops like in the regular MongoTemplate aren't available however. Is there another method available?

Comment: What's your intent behind this exercise? Have you tried `Document command = new Document("$eval", "sleep(5000)"); ReactiveMongoTemplate.executeCommand(command);`?

Comment: mp911de thanks for the big hint already! I tried running it, and when using a .block() on the executeCommand's returning flux I can tell it sleeps for 5 seconds. After that, I do get an exception though. I assume this might be some kind of bug in the reactive mongo library? I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Can you provide your code (controller, dependencies) or a Github repo to reproduce the issue? I'm not able to figure out what's wrong. The message indicates that WebFlux isn't able to serialize (write) the response.

Comment: This might be linked to: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16166, if your code is ultimately trying to serialize `BigDecimal` as JSON.

Comment: That was indeed the issue, thanks Brian Clozel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mp911de I've come to the following code that helps me make the MongoDB sleep

```
@Override
public Mono<BloodSample> findBloodSample(String pigId) {
    final Document command = new Document("$eval", "sleep(5000)");
    return reactiveMongoTemplate.executeCommand(command, ReadPreference.nearest())
            .onErrorResume(error -> null)
            .then(Mono.just(new BloodSample(BigDecimal.valueOf(10 + r.nextInt()))));
}
```